# Swift iOS Sprite Kit - What is the best way to load in sprites?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures

With my current code, I'm using texture Atlas's which are being loaded throughout the game. This usually loads about 2-4, small, low res images in one go. I thought this was the best way to load images in, but my game noticeably lag spikes.

Here is a snippet of code I'm using:

```
let wallAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walls")

var topPoleSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: wallAtlas.textureNamed("pole-top-\(randomInt2)"))
var textureTopSprite = wallAtlas.textureNamed("pole-top-1")
topPoleSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: textureTopSprite, size: topPoleSprite.size)
self.addChild(topPoleSprite)
```

What is the best way to do this? Is this method loading in images every time, that could be pre-loaded at the beginning? Should I just load images straight from images.xcassets?

Thanks!
Toby.

Comment: You should always preload your texture atlas as well as other assets such as sounds before starting the main game play to avoid lag later.

Comment: @sangony How does one go about doing this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTextureAtlas/preloadTextureAtlases:withCompletionHandler:

Comment: There's also an excellent project on GitHub. Look at the section called PRELOADING for some good code examples. https://github.com/ios8/AdventureBuildingaSpriteKitGameUsingSwift/blob/master/Adventure/Adventure%20Shared/Scene/AdventureScene.swift